# Windows 7 (64 bit) SP1 stuck on welcome screen with wmi error

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, boot, wmi

My desktop (Intel i5 @ 3.10 ghz, 8 gb ram, 1 gb nvidia graphics card, Dell s2240L full HD monitor) that runs Win 7 (64 bit) SP1 gets stuck on each startup on welcome screen after I enter the password. I need to hard reset the PC for 3-4 times and then only the login is successful. This happens on every startup but never on a restart.

When I check event logs I get this error every time -

Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.

This freeze happens only on startup and once I am in after 3-4 login attempts, PC runs just fine.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Psycogeek - That (fix on MS support website) seems to have solved the problem for me! My Windows used to get stuck on every start-up but last few start-ups since I applied that fix were smooth :) Thanks! If you can move your comment as an answer I will mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

From http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2545227

There is a MS Fix-It located at the above link.

> This originated in the Windows 7 SP1 DVD/ISO creation process. There
>   was an issue in the creation process that caused a WMI registration to
>   remain in the DVD/ISO. Since the registration is designed to work only
>   during the DVD/ISO creation process, it fails to run on a live system
>   and causes these events. These events are not indicative of any issue
>   in the system and can be safely ignored. If however you want to
>   prevent these events from getting generated and want to remove this
>   specific WMI registration manually, please follow the steps mentioned
>   in this article for running the workaround script.

---

*Fix-It Yourself by creating a script*.

To resolve the issue, run a script to stop the Event ID 10 messages. To run the script follow these steps:

1) In Notepad create a new document named Workaround.txt

2) Copy the following script into notepad

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
& strComputer & "\root\subscription")

Set obj1 = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from __eventfilter where name='BVTFilter' and query='SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA ""Win32_Processor"" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99'")

For Each obj1elem in obj1

set obj2set = obj1elem.Associators_("__FilterToConsumerBinding")

set obj3set = obj1elem.References_("__FilterToConsumerBinding")

For each obj2 in obj2set

 WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

 WScript.echo obj2.GetObjectText_

 obj2.Delete_

next

For each obj3 in obj3set

 WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

 WScript.echo obj3.GetObjectText_

 obj3.Delete_

next

WScript.echo "Deleting the object"

WScript.echo obj1elem.GetObjectText_

obj1elem.Delete_

Next
```

3) Save the text as Workaround.vbs

4) Close Notepad

5) Open an elevated command prompt

a. Click on start

b. Click on Programs

c. Right-Click on Command Prompt

d. Choose run as administrator

6) Change Directory to the one containing workaround.vbs: ( Example CD c:\users\%username%

7) Run cscript workaround.vbs

After running the script the Event ID 10 errors related to this event should stop occurring. This does not remove any of the existing entries in the Event log, they would need to be manually cleared out of the application event log.

Note: There can be other reasons for Event ID 10 error messages, this only prevents the error message listed above from occurring.

*The information above was copied Directly from the microsoft link above, in the case that the link fails or the information is no longer available.*

Comment: Unfortunately, the problematic start-up has started reoccurring today. Those WMI messages are suppressed and not visible in event logs anymore but Windows still gets stuck on startup.

Comment: That makes sence to me, because If i am reading it right the error is not something that would stop the system. So you still likely have a problem beyond this thing showing up in the event logs.   And it is also likely to be something in one of the "run" things , startup runs.  Boot into safe mode, see if that works fine. Use autoruns (or even hijackthis in this case) to diagnose the junk you have that starts up.

Comment: Those WMI errors from event logs have disappeared but I don't get to see an error every time Windows is stuck. I am going to try all that you mentioned and see what's causing this. Those inputs will certainly help. Also since this happens only during startup and once logged in system runs smooth, can we rule out any hardware related issues? Is it most likely to be a software/drivers issue?

Comment: Yes likely to be software.  Correction made here ,It would be easy to test the hardware for cooling and stability in this case, because you could run a hard task (prime small) Ram (prime large), and a gpu benching thing (furmark, haven, something) to quickly verify that (mostly).

Comment: I have tried this by deselecting all start-up items and all non-MS start-up services but Windows is still freezing on welcome. It's a really hard trial and error process as every time this doesn't work, I have to go through the painful process start-up which goes through only after 3-4 attempts. Any other clues?

Comment: @Mandar When the welcome screen hits it is some of the first very hard things for the cpu and ram and all. Sorry I should have seen that. It is a good idication that your "system isn't stable" It is likely that doing an IntelBurnTest or Prime Small testing would also show that, check your temps while running these very hard cpu tasks. It could be temperatures, overclocking or turbo speeds failing at the cpu, ram timing, voltages that are to low for the speeds and timing.

Comment: Hmm, so you are saying it can be a hardware problem as well. Let me check that and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried connecting my CPU to another monitor and to my surprise I didn't face any problem. Login/start-up was smooth. What could be wrong with my monitor? I have tried to install original monitor drivers that came in CD and also tried updating drivers but the problem is still there. (Monitor description is in the question)

Comment: Well that would be odd. There are ways that an electrical problem can end up with power going the wrong way, or like power existing between the 2 grounds. (voltage existing , possibly even a tiny spark seen when connecting the outer ground metal of the monitor). It is unlikely to be a driver thing with monitors, because the monitor driver doesnt DO much. Possibly that a much higher resolution makes the machine work harder.

Comment: It turns out my nvidia graphics card had some problems. I have taken it off for now and login is working great! I will now try and get a replacement for that. Thank you Psycogeek for your inputs all along :)